# How to FIND and CLICK the elements in Inspect Element using Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I managed to navigate through the sites but I landed on a site that **has Javascript and Ajax**. The code in the View Source and Inspect Element **are not the same**.

Using Selenium, I can **only** click elements that are present in the **View Source** code.

My current code is this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("libraryTab_ManagementPackagesTable_productNameGroup_appdynamics")).Click();
```

But the application **crashes** since the element **is in Inspect Element code**, not in View Source.

Comment: View source is the original html from the server.  Inspect element is what is currently present, so it makes sense that you are getting an element not found error when looking up an id that isn't in the inspect element.   My suggestion is to try and select the element using jquery in the browser's debugger.  If you can,  then pass that selector to selenium's cssselector.

Comment: it may be dynamic element created by an action so you need to perform that action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your element not present in initial page source, but created dynamically, you might need to use `ExplicitWait`. Try below code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("libraryTab_ManagementPackagesTable_productNameGroup_appdynamics")));
element.Click();
```

With above code you should be able to wait (not more than 15 seconds) until element generated and it is clickable. Otherwise, you'll get `TimeOutException`. You can increase or decrease timeout.